# How can I make sure message m ∈ Zp

Tags: math, encryption, data-conversion

I am implementing ORUTA and using JPBC library for it.
In one of the algorithms, for hashing a message, it is specified that for message m:

m ∈ Zp, for some large prime number p.(may be this is equal to m < p)

I have a message text, so how can I make sure that the above equation holds true?

This question is different from https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/44340/how-can-i-make-sure-message-m-%e2%88%88-zp. I want algorithm whose steps I can follow to write the program in java.

Also here I have a big m. How can i convert that m into chunks of m so that equation holds for each chunk?
Thanks for help :)

Comment: What do you mean by saying the question is different? It is verbatim the same and you are the author of that other question. It seems that you are not happy with the answers that you received, but why not isn't very clear (especially since one of them *does* give Java code). `m ∈ Zp` just means that `m` isn't too big. To be explicit, the number of bytes in `m` must be less than the base 2 logarithm of `p`.  Perhaps you can rephrase the question so that it doesn't seem virtually identical to the question you already asked.

Comment: Actually My m is very big and I want to divide it in chunks so that m is <p. What I was thinking is that first I have to convert message into byte which will give byte array.then convert them to bigint to check whether that is small than p. Now according to you, I have to count the number of bytes to be less than base 2 log p(and not the actual byte values compared to p). Right?

Comment: and is that java code given as answer in previous question correct?

Comment: I don't know what ORUTA is and my Java is rudimentary. Secure implementation of cryptographical primitives is a somewhat involved topic since a poor implementation can introduce security weaknesses. Perhaps it would be a good use of time to read the source of good Java implementations of a standard hash algorithms before you implement a new hash algorithm. Many of the same issues of how to break data up into chunks which can be thought of as numbers would pop up there. Also, if you can find an implementation of this ORUTA in another language such as C then you could use that as a guide.

Comment: Thanks @john. But, for this question, knowledge of ORUTA is not required. All necessary things are mentioned in question. I only want to know that how to compare a string to a number. According to the answer at previous question, I have to work with byte value of m. What you say is number of bytes in m. Which one is right? And why compare to *log* p?

Comment: I should have said that the number of *bits* is less than the base 2 logarithm of `p`. This is because anything which fits into `k` bits can be interpreted as a number in the range `0` to `2^k - 1` and if `2^k - 1 < p` then `k` is less than the base-2 logarithm of `p` A natural way to handle this is to make a decision that e.g. you are going to use 512 bit blocks and then make sure that the `p` you pick has at least 512 bits. Don't think of adjusting the message to the prime -- think of adjusting the prime to the intended block size.

Comment: You're asking a very complex question from a cryptographic perspective. You need to look at protocols like TLS with OAEP as to how these things are done properly. Otherwise, you're reinventing a (flawed) wheel.

Comment: I think the question, as best I understand it, is the same.

Comment: @KashyapKotak I haven't looked into the description of ORUTA, but I'm pretty sure that your `m` is supposed to be randomly chosen. It's then encrypted with ORUTA. That `m` is also hashed with some hash function in order to get a byte array which can be used as a key for AES or similar. Then your actual plaintext is encrypted with AES and the key is derived from a "message" that was encrypted with ORUTA. This is called a [key encapsulation mechanism](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Key_encapsulation).

Answer (score 1):

> Also here I have a big m. How can i convert that m into chunks of m so
>   that equation holds for each chunk?

It is not completely clear to me what you're asking, nor do I know what "ORUTA" is. However, here is at least a java example of one method of breaking a large integer into an array of integers of size less than p. However, depending on the details of "ORUTA" it may not be acceptable.

```java
/**
 * Returns an array of BigIntegers, each one of which is < p. The array represents the
 * radix p expansion of m, in big-endian order.
 *
 * @param m an integer, m >= 0.
 * @param p an integer, p > 1.
 * @return an array of BigIntegers.
 */
private static BigInteger[] breakIntoChunks(BigInteger m, BigInteger p) {
    assert m.signum() >= 0 && p.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE) > 0;
    if (m.signum() == 0) { /* m == 0 is a special case. */
        return new BigInteger[]{BigInteger.ZERO};
    }
    ArrayList<BigInteger> chunks = new ArrayList<>();
    while (m.signum() != 0) {
        BigInteger[] divRem = m.divideAndRemainder(p);
        chunks.add(0, divRem[1]);
        m = divRem[0];
    }
    return chunks.toArray(new BigInteger[0]);
}
```

Comment: Thanks. But, here m represents text. m is a message not Integer. For eg. My name "Kashyap Chetan Kotak". Now I want chunks of this text to be < p. Like if the whole string is larger than p and if 3 chunks are necessary so that each is less than p, then it may be like: "Kashyap" < p; "Chetan" < p; "Kotak" < p.